# Getting Unknown Charcters from Twitter Api

Tags: php, curl, twitter, unicode, character-encoding

I am using **https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json** twitter api for getting tweets from some particular account and getting all tweets properly except tweets in other language rather than English.

**Php Code for making request to Twitter is below:**

```
    $ch = curl_init();
         curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,1);
         curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,"grant_type=client_credentials");        
         curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
         curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
         curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);
         curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Tweet Fetcher PHP 0.0.1");
         curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
         curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
         curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST,2);
         curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,array('Authorization: '.$authType.'
 '.$authValue,'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8'));
         $result = curl_exec($ch);
         curl_close($ch);
```

**Getting some tweets Results as**

```
à¤®à¥‡à¤¹à¤¨à¤¤ à¤”à¤° à¤®à¥‹à¤¬à¤¾à¤‡à¤² à¤¨à¥‡ à¤šà¤®à¤•à¤¾à¤ˆ
```

How to get this string in proper charset?

**Update Code**:

```
$tweet = json_decode($result);
```

**But getting same results**

Comment: Can you give us the Twitter ID of the Tweet which is causing you issues?

Comment: @TerenceEden https://twitter.com/WithCongress is the account from which i am trying to get tweets. it include tweets in hindi language as well as in English also. i am facing problem with hindi fonts tweets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's take a look at the API response you're getting.

https://apigee.com/snapshot/twitter?snapId=apigee-console-snapshots-1388552400000_03b4cb5a-7817-4eba-8e66-1d622deb8c27

```
{
  "created_at": "Wed Jan 08 10:02:49 +0000 2014",
  "id": 420858117375553540,
  "id_str": "420858117375553537",
  "text": "पंजाब ड्रग्स गिरोह में मंत्री बिक्रम मजीथीआ का नाम सामने आया। श्री राहुल गांधी ने इस बारे में बहुत पहले बताया था। http://t.co/TQHGZxALQU",
  "source": "web",
  "truncated": false,
  "in_reply_to_status_id": null,
 ...etc...
```

There is literally nothing wrong there.  The "text" is UTF-8 and will be handled properly by PHP.

What is probably happening is that you haven't set the meta tags on your page to display UTF-8.  It's probably set to a Windows Charset.

At the top of your page, use something like

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

To force the output to the correct encoding.